# JS check if chrome iwallet extension is installed on user chrome browser or not?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing wallet to pay for e-commerce websites.
I need to add a check on the JS page if the user has installed chrome extension ( iwallet ) or not.

Answer (score 0):

As said in a previous answer you can't do that. That's because if such a thing was actually present it will be a privacy issue for the chrome users.
Actually the chrome web store is the only website that has access to such a chrome api.

BUT - looking at the [source code](https://github.com/lucusfly/iost-extension) of the extension you can check what the extension is altering in you browser or even which messages its listening to.

In the Iwallet source code I found in `content-script.js` and `inpage.js` that it sets a special window object property `window.IWalletJS` and you can simply check if it exist to determine if the extension is installed or not.

As simple as:

```
if('IWalletJS' in window){
    console.log("IWallet is installed", window.IWalletJS);
} else {
    console.log("IWallet is not installed");
}
```

Take a look at the object attached to this property you can check if  the user is logged, account name and more.